# editing the values in a csv file in a project throws an "index out of range" error

Tags: swift, file, replace

I am trying to modify a program that was contracted by my company before I came to work there. The program uses a .csv file to contain the product numbers and values based on the product number. It seemed simple enough to remove the old file from the current project, and replace the old file with the new file of the same name. I changed the values in 1 record to make the update to pricing. There were no other changes.

After I deleted the old file by highlighting the file in the project, select delete and then select move to trash. I bring the new file in by dragging and dropping from finder. When the Choose options for adding these files comes up, I make sure the check box copy items if needed is checked. I also ensure that Added folders has the option button Create folder references is selected. Add to targets has my project name and is checked. Then I select finish.
When I try to run the program, I get an index out of range error.

While debugging I found that the columns loaded from the file look like this.

```
["DDN080120000MG35", "DDN.08.01.20000MG35", "DDN.08.01.20000 HE MG35", "MK28708-2000", "Solid Carbide Drill", "Aluminum", "Internal", "8 X D", "20", "20", "243", "190", "160", "484.00 €", "\"$\t715.60\"\r"]
["\u{1A}"]
```

The last record of the file doesn't have the `["\u{1A}"]` shown just above. I ran the old program in debug and this doesn't appear when I set a breakpoint.

Does `["\u{1A}"]` represent an EOF marker that shouldn't be there? Am I missing some sort of compile action that I need to take with the file before I load it? I'm lost. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hey there. Could you provide more information about your program? This sounds like a problem with having a number of columns that doesn't match what your program expects. However, it's difficult to know if this is the case without looking at the code that is parsing your CSV files.

Comment: private class HornPricingDataRow {
  
  let columns: [String]
  
  init(columns: [String]) {
  
  print(columns)
    
    assert (columns[HornDataColumnType.MaterialNumber.rawValue].count > 0)
    
    self.columns = columns
    
  }

Comment: @ToddM63 Please add relevant information to the question, not in the comments. And add also the code to *edit the values*.

Comment: There is also a problem in the last field of the line you edited. \r is a carriage return and \t is a tab you probably don’t want. Looks like you’ve used a visual text editor to edit the file which has inserted unwanted characters. Go back to the original file and edit it in Xcode instead.

Comment: Dale, you are correct. I had copied the file from Excel and when it was moved to the project, I opened it in IOS numbers. They handle files differently so that's what was causing my issues. Thanks for the advice. I was lucky enough to stumble over the answer when I saw that saving the file was trying to save it to numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The issue wasn't with the code. It was with the difference between Windows and IOS system and how they handle files. The numbers program in IOS was attaching a character at the end of the .csv file that already had an EOF marker on it. Xcode was confusing the original EOF marker from an Excel file as a record in the file causing an index out of range error. The answer was to open the original csv file in TextEdit, make the modifications and saving it back as a csv. Once I dropped it into the project, the problem was solved.